# Can't retrieve background image CSS, file pathing isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css, image

Context: am using Mac. I am trying to build an HTML webpage and I can't get an image on my computer to show in the background despite trying multiple solutions I've looked up. The background just appears as whitespace. I am convinced there is something wrong with my file pathing because when I type in the file path I get "permission denied" or "command not found" despite copying the exact file path using Option-Command-C. However, I have no idea how to fix it despite many attempts now.

```
...
<body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylemapUI.css">
  <div class="menus">

    <ul>
      <li>Contact</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li>J</li>
          <li>J</li>
          <li>S</li>
          <li>J</li>
        </ul>
      <li>About</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Vision</li>
          <li>Leadership</li>
          <li>Mission Statement</li>
          <li>Background</li>
        </ul>
      <li>Social</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Twitter</li>
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>Discord</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
...
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  margin:auto;
  width:500px;
  height:auto;
  background-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-image:url("/Users/myname/Project_Atlas/templates/pic1.jpg");

}
```

I expect the background image to cover the entire webpage but it just appears as whitespace in the background. I also notice that the text in my list shifts to the left as if some element is being loaded, but there's nothing but whitespace.

Comment: Your CSS has a class `.body` but no element in your example has that class. Your HTML also appears to have elements outside of the `<body>` which is invalid.

Comment: replaced .body with body but the same result occurs. Also attempted using .menus class with the same results.

Comment: Are you sure your stylesheet is linked correctly?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `file://linkhere`

Comment: Note that typically images are stored in a subfolder of or the same folder as the one containing the HTML or CSS file. Having the image in another folder like your user folder makes deploying it to a web server more difficult.

Comment: I see that may be the issue because I can't seem to edit the text style using the CSS file. I confirmed the spelling is correct and the filetype is correct.

Comment: Can you try `background-image: url("file:///Users/myname/Project_Atlas/templates/pic1.jpg");`

Comment: Attempted, still the same result

Comment: Could you try putting your <link> in <head> instead?

Comment: I attempted that as well but no success.

Comment: Could you open `file:///Users/myname/Project_Atlas/templates/pic1.jpg` in your browser directly? Does the image exist?

Comment: Does it work with pictures on the internet? Ex: url("https://https:/.....png");

Comment: 1. Check that your css path is correct, i.e. stylemapUI.css exists in the same folder as this HTML.
2. Don't give the absolute path of the image. A good practice is to have an images folder so that image path is "images/pic1.jpg". Even if not so, the path of image you are providing should be relative to the css file here. And you don't need the prefix "file://" in most cases. Try this and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: your html structure for the lists is also wrong - the sub child `ul` needs to be inside the `li`, not after it and the url needs to be relative to the stylesheet.  If it's absolute like you re using, then it needs to be relative to the root of the site.  If it's not within your site folder structure, then make sure that your what ever is serving your website has permissions to show the image - I've found that in the past if things are in a users folder, the webserver does not have the permissions to access it

Comment: Solved! I was editing a copy of this HTML file that did not exist in the same folder as the CSS one. After navigating to the file and opening it, I was able to load the background image. @Akash I was able to get it to work using only the image name instead of the full file path. Thank you for letting me know. @Pete can you point out which ```li```  the ```ul``` should be in? Thanks

Comment: This is what your list should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/dszo028L - all sub ul should be within an li - a ul cannot be a child of another ul